# How to rewrite the equals method

Tags: java, equals

I saw a colleague write it as follows:

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final ImageCode other = (ImageCode) obj;
    if ((this.code == null) ? (other.code != null) : !this.code.equals(other.code)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, I suggested changing it for this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
         return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Parent)){
         return false;
    }
    final ImageCode other = (ImageCode) obj;
    if ((this.code == null) ? (other.code != null) : !this.code.equals(other.code)) {
         return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

but he told me that it is wrong, and that `instanceof` can't be used for the `equals` method. I don't understand why he said that.

Comment: Can't say. Have you tried to run your equals override with some debug lines?

Comment: Class C extends B. And B extends A. Then object c is instanceof C(or B or A). Doesn't mean c and b(or a) is the same class.

Comment: @Hooch,@waltersu ,but i have tested for extending,i could't found any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` in `equals`. Java uses it all the time. See e.g. [`String`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;

        // More code ...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@dejvuth,
If anObject is instance of String then why do we need to typecast. You can directly use it. I think its ok to go ahead without checking instanceOf.
Just you may need to type cast the object. You can check my code here.

http://www.javavni.com/is-hashcode---and-equals---required-together.html